# Google Drive APi with clean WEB API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, google-drive-api

i wanted to use the Google Drive API along with a simple WEB API 2 - Project.
Somehow the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs is missing.

What i use:
Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
Empty Template with WEB API

My steps:

1. Creating the empty project including WEB API
2. building the    project
3. updating packages via Nuget Packager
4. Install-Package    Google.Apis.Drive.v2 (using this guide:    https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs)
5. Copy and Paste the code from the above link into a clean    api-controller:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<string> Get()
   {
       UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
           new ClientSecrets
           {
               ClientId = "228492645857-5599mgcfnhrr74a7er1do1chpam4rnbt.apps.googleusercontent.com",
               ClientSecret = "onoyJQaUazQK4VsKUjD63sDu",
           },
           new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
           "user",
           CancellationToken.None).Result;

       // Create the service.
       var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
       });

       File body = new File();
       body.Title = "My document";
       body.Description = "A test document";
       body.MimeType = "text/plain";

       byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Projects\VS\DataAnime\DataAnime\document.txt");
       System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

       FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
       request.Upload();

       File file = request.ResponseBody;

       return new string[] { file.Id, "value2" };
   }
   ```
6. building

   6.1 Error: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs is missing

   6.2 Google says following error in browser:

> 400. That’s an error.
>        Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
>      Application: Project Default Service Account
>
>      You can email the developer of this application at: xxxx@gmail.com
>
>      The redirect URI in the request: http://example.com:63281/authorize/ did not match a registered
>        redirect URI.

```
http://example.com:63281/authorize/ was neither the url i am using for my project nor the url i registered in my developer console (this errorshowing-port is changeing everytime i run this project.
```

Has anyone an idea why is that?
No other sources helped fixing this weird issue.

Comment: I have checked document, it says, when you have created google credential, there you must have specified `redirect url` and that redirect url does not match with localhost:port.

Comment: I know, i already made this redirect-url to my project url.
If i debug the class as mentioned above is missing and that is why the error is showing up i think.

Comment: can you tell me , what is redirect url in google credential setup?

Comment: In the developer tools the redirct url is http://example.com:xxxx/signin-google

And my project goes along with http://example.com:xxxx.
To be honest, i don't know where /signin-google comes from.
Nevertheless the error says its example.com:xxxx/authorize.
So i am little bit confused of it.

Comment: I thought of saying add `/authorize` to main url, but as you told, google add something else, not sure why, still i'll try to find solution.

Comment: Tried to change to example.com.xxx/api/apiController, but same error is shown: example.com.xxxx/authorize did not match the registered url. I bet it has something to do with the missing GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new project on https://console.developers.google.com for a native software instead of a web-client project, even i am using a web client.

There is just one weird thing:
If i debug my code, it still says that GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs is missing.
Without debugging i can do everything i want.

Thank you very much for your help.